# jQuery: Given a selector, find only its visible elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hidden

This should be an easy one. I have a variable that I've already declared called $listItems. The declaration looks like this:

```
var $listItems = $ul.children('li'); // $ul is just a selected unordered list
```

Later in my code, I'd like to only get the ones that are currently visible. How would I go about that? Something like:

```
$listItems.parent().children(':visible')?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to narrow down a set of elements to only those that match a selector (or a function), like this:

```
$listItems.filter(':visible')
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant Nick ;)

Comment: this is especially helpful if you need to filter on multiple values.  E.g. selected and visible.  +1 for a good solution!

Comment: FWIW, jQuery defines an element as visible "if they consume space in the document". An element could have its `visibility` set to `hidden`, so it's not actually seen on the page, but `:visible` would still return the element.

Answer (score 4):

You have it with the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector. It can be used in any of the jQuery collection methods `$()`, `filter()`, `children()`, `find()`, etc.

**Note:** There is a difference between something that is *visible* on the page and has its `visibility` property set.